# In a tight spot with Venting a bar sink in basement

Tags: basement, sink, vent

We're adding a bar sink into the basement of our house while we are finishing it. The location is at a place where we can attach to the drain just fine. The issue I am running into is that I am not able to or clearly almost impossible to connect to an existing vent on another end of the basement due to HVAC.

However, I do have a much cleaner direct path to an outside wall. I am in Minnesota and the currently adopted code is 2015 version. http://epubs.iapmo.org/2015/Minnesota/index.html

Now the location that the vent would exit the sidewall meets all these criteria. I want to know if I am going to have any issues and I don't see why I could not do it this way.

- Not directly below a door, openable window, or other air intake opening (of this or any other building).
- Not within 10 feet horizontally of the above-mentioned openings, unless it's 3 feet above them.
- Not less than 10 feet from the property line.
- Not less than 10 feet above the ground.
- Not under the soffit, if soffit vents are used (Covered by point 1 in my opinion).
- Must be protected from birds and/or rodents blocking it.

Comment: As it is a code related inquiry, you should copy and paste the relevant code provisions, or indicate the section, in the question. Otherwise, unless a person happen to be familiar with the MN residential code, no one can respond with certainty without going through the code.

Comment: Have you investigated air admissions valves (AAV?)